# Rest API response headers for json data?

Tags: json, rest, http, curl

This is likely a duplicate but I wasn't able to word my query in a way that yielded a situation like mine. Thanks for any help answering or refining the question.

I've implemented a simple REST api in java / apache camel. When I invoke an endpoint with a `GET` request from my ***browser***, I get the response I expect:

### From my browser:

`GET http://localhost:8080/app/pipeline?text=hello`

`{"input":"hello"}`

#### Request Headers:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8080
Pragma:no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

#### Response Headers:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, 
Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, CONNECT, PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:31
Content-Type:application/json
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

### From Curl:

Now the problem comes in when I hit the same endpoint via curl:

```
$ curl -i 'http://localhost:8080/app/pipeline?text=hi' 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 42
Accept: */*
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DELETE,TRACE,OPTIONS,CONNECT,PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
text: hi
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive

"eyJpbnB1dCI6ImhpIiwibWV0YWRhdGEiOnt9fQ=="
```

I get this weird encoded response above. I'm learning about the Accept and Encoding type headers, so I set the accept and content-encoding header like my request from chrome had:

```
$ curl -i -sH 'Accept: application/json' -sH 'Content-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br' 'http://localhost:8080/app/pipeline?text=hi' 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 42
Accept: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,     Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, CONNECT, PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Content-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
text: hi
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive

"eyJpbnB1dCI6ImhpIiwibWV0YWRhdGEiOnt9fQ=="
```

What the heck? It turns out that unless I specify the Accept header exactly how it was in the chrome request, I get this weird output. With that header set I get the desired response:

```
$ curl -i -sH 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -sH 'Content-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br' 'http://localhost:8080/app/pipeline?text=hi' 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 28
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,     Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, CONNECT, PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Content-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
text: hi
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive

{"input":"hi","metadata":{}}
```

## The Question

I'm returning application/json from my service, so why does my request not work unless I specify the header like this: `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8` ? I assume `*/*` includes everything, but it doesn't work if I **just** supply `*/*` in the header, or if I **just** supply application/json.

Any leads in the right direction to understanding are much appreciated.

Comment: Which java framework are you using?  can you add some code of how the server has been implemented? The server is responding with a base64 encoded string that contains the following text: `{"input":"hi","metadata":{}}`

Comment: Remember that the `Accept` header has to be parsed by another program written by some other guy. If I was that guy and I was trying to determine whether to send JSON, I would probably focus on `application/json` and possibly forget to consider `*/*` ;-)